# Constant Contact API

Tags: php, api, oauth, constantcontact

I'm trying to write a simple Constant Contact script for adding and updating emails. The script is simple enough and should've ran smoothly. But when I start to include 'src/Ctct/autoload.php' the page just returns blank. I tried running it on another server and it works. But on my working server, it returns blank. It uses OAuth authentication from CTCT. I think it's a setting in the server, but I have no control over the server and any changes need to be forwarded to an admin, I just don't know what I need to change.

Here's the code:

```
require "Scripts/ConstantContact/src/Ctct/autoload.php";
use Ctct\ConstantContact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\Contact;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\ContactList;
use Ctct\Components\Contacts\EmailAddress;
use Ctct\Exceptions\CtctException;

define("APIKEY", "*** Censored Media (18+ only) ***");
define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "*** Censored Media (18+ only) ***");

$cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);

// attempt to fetch lists in the account, catching any exceptions and printing the errors to screen
    $lists = $cc->getLists(ACCESS_TOKEN);

    $action = "Getting Contact By Email Address";
    $Email = "asdf@asdf.com";
    $FirstName = "Asdf";
    $LastName = "Ghjk";
        // check to see if a contact with the email addess already exists in the account
        $response = $cc->getContactByEmail(ACCESS_TOKEN, $Email);

        // create a new contact if one does not exist
        if (empty($response->results)) {
            $action = "Creating Contact";

            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->addEmail($Email);
            $contact->addList('1');
            $contact->first_name = $FirstName;
            $contact->last_name = $LastName;
            $returnContact = $cc->addContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact); 

        // update the existing contact if address already existed
        } else {            
            $action = "Updating Contact";

            $contact = $response->results[0];
            $contact->addList('1');
            $contact->first_name = $FirstName;
            $contact->last_name = $LastName;
            $returnContact = $cc->updateContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact);  
        }

    // catch any exceptions thrown during the process and print the errors to screen


    if (isset($returnContact)) {
        echo '<div class="container alert-success"><pre class="success-pre">';
        print_r($returnContact); 
        echo '</pre></div>';
    }
print '<p>'.$action.'</p>';
```

Again, this works on another server I tried, but doesn't work on my working server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to get any logging out of this to see what might be causing the blank page? Have you thought if posting to a free (where you control it) hosting service so that you have more control and debugging? Remember that if you move hosts, the URL associated with API Key / Access Token needs to be changed.

Comment: Hi Jed. Yup, I found out what was causing the problem. The API requires PHP 5.3 or higher, just as Mike said, and my server is running on PHP 5.2. I've tested it on another server and it works. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running PHP 5.3 or higher on the other server?  Also did the domain change at all, if so that may throw an exception resulting in a blank page as your API key is domain specific.  Feel free to shoot me an email and I will be glad to help you out with this - mstowe [at] constantcontact.com

-Mike